# Undefined index: surname in laravel

Tags: laravel

If I run execute this it brings out an error undefined index:surname.

```
The  view blade
@for($i= 0;$i < count($data); $i++)
 <p>{{ $data[$i]['surname'] }}</p> @endfor
```

Route file web. php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/pizza', function () {
$data =[
     [ 'surname' => 'abdulmalik'],
    ['firstname'=>'hassan'],
    ['middlename'=>'umar'],
    ['dob'=>'25/3/1992'],
    ['age'=>10]
];

return view('about'['data'=>$data]);


});
```

Comment: Did you forget the `,` between `'about'` and `['data'`? Like this: `view('about', ['data'=>$data]);` or is it just pasted incorrectly?

Comment: I have tried your code and found no errors except `,` like @emotality said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be:

```
$data =[
    [
        'surname' => 'abdulmalik',
        'firstname'=>'hassan',
        'middlename'=>'umar',
        'dob'=>'25/3/1992',
        'age'=>10
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data as an associative array and then accordingly iterate in the blade file.

```
$data =[
     'surname' => 'abdulmalik',
    'firstname'=>'hassan',
    'middlename'=>'umar',
    'dob'=>'25/3/1992',
    'age'=>10
];
```

In your blade file.

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <p> {{key}} : {{ $value }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: If your query was resolved. Kindly mark it as the solution .